# Raspberry Pi 2 - cannot enable /dev/i2c-0

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c

i have a problem  with  bit banging  on raspberry pi 2 i have done   all of these  step :

```
*sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf  //#blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

`*sudo nano /etc/modules //Add the Line i2c-dev at the end of the file`.
*Edit the /boot/cmdline.txt file: `sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt` //At the end of the line add  `bcm2708.vc_i2c_override=1`  and when  i run `ls /dev/i2c*`   i get only  `/dev/i2c-1.` any  ideas?    im  using  Raspberry pi 2.thanks

**I'm expecting to see `/dev/i2c-1` and `/dev/i2c-0` instead of only `/dev/i2c-1`.**

Comment: Besides there is better place to ask raspberry pi related questions http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add

```
dtparam=i2c_vc=on
```

to

```
/boot/config.txt
```

by nano for example

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Then I can see both i2c interfaces on my Raspberry Pi 2 running Debian Wheezy version.

Later on you can have a problem with detecting i2c devices on the bus. Please take a look to this thread on Raspberry Pi official forum with next steps. [i2c-0 on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=115709&p=789932&hilit=i2c0#p789932)

> Those gpios don't have external pull ups to 3V3. They will default to
>   the internal 50k pull-ups to 3V3 but they not be sufficient to drive
>   the bus. I'd try adding a 2k pull up to 3V3 on each pin (i2c-1 has
>   external 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3).

Comment: thank you very much  but the i2cdetect  -y 0  doesn't show   any thnig

Comment: the  I2C0  pins   are  27   and   28   should  i  make  pull up  resitors?

Comment: Yes it looks so. Please take a look to this thread https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=115709&p=789932&hilit=i2c0#p789932

Comment: the pins are   27  and  28  or 28 and 29 ?

Comment: According to the link I gave you in the previous comment SDA=27 and SCL=28.

Comment: Please follow instruction in the link I shared to you because this guy had this same problem like you have now and he overcome it with the help of the guys. So I believe whole essential info is there.

Comment: Did you check on the oscilloscope/logic analyzer whether i2c frames are forming?

Comment: Anyways I think you should close this topic and reopen new one with description of your new problem. Because your initial question is already answered.